# What makes the need of a definite article?

Tags: articles

> (i) He works (a) **at night** and sleeps (b) **during the day**. 
> (ii) Nocturnal animals
>   sleep (c) **by day** and hunt (d) **by night**.
>   (source: [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/day))

There’s a definite article in (b), while there're zero articles in the others.
Why does (b) need one, while the others don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those bolded examples are adverbial phrases, that is, a group of words acting together as an adverb.

As often is the case with phrases, it is easier to learn their meanings than reasoning about them. I think your question gives a good example where the article use cannot be deducted from the meaning of the phrase.

The collocation dictionary [ozdic](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/day) lists three meanings of day when used with a preposition. Note that the meaning depends on the preposition, and not on the article:

**Preposition + day**

1. period of 24 hours

   - **by the day**: He's getting stronger by the day.
   - **for a day**: They stayed for a day.
   - **in a day**: We hope to finish the job in a day.
   - **on the day of**: On the day of his wedding he was very nervous.
2. time between sunrise and sunset

   - **by day**: We travelled at night and rested by day.
   - **during the day**: He sleeps during the day
   - **for the day**: We went to the seaside for the day.
3. particular period of time

   - **in somebody's day**: Things were very different in my grandfather's day.
   - **of the day**: the government of the day

Comment: +1 I'd also like to add this information. In *Practical English Grammar* (Michael Swan), **70.1 common expressions without articles**, there is a good explanation: "in some common fixed expressions to do with place, time and movement, normally countable nouns are treated as uncountables, without articles."

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. Let me write what I think here. However, NSs would help us understand this in a better way.

> He works at night and sleeps during the day.

I think the word *day* took the definite article because here, in this context, a person's routine and time period is **already defined** in the first clause - *he works at night*. Probably, the day is *definite* as it **follows** the night described in that sentence.

> Nocturnal animals sleep by day and hunt by night.

Adding *the* will make it *"...animals sleep **by the day**..."* which would mean [something different](http://www.yourdictionary.com/by-the-day).

Comment: “During the day” seems not that simple. Because I find a sentence in Corpus of Con-temporary American English, “What kept you going during the day at night?”. And I also got these examples: “I teach during the day and do research at night”;" The crabs hide during the day and come out at night". So I get the feeling that ‘during the day’ alone has a definite article for denoting some meaning. There are variety of the examples in [this Korean website](http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=ekw000202842&q=during+the+day).

Comment: @Listenever True but then if you carefully reread them all, you'll find some context of defining it as *the day*. As in *I teach...* you have *night* with it so the same context; in crab's example also, it's crabs' routine and thus *the*.

Comment: I rather think that it’s the preposition during that license the definite article. For I can find dur-ing the night. Don’t you think the meaning of during forces the use of the?

Comment: @Listenever using *the* with during is quite common but then I already searched COCAE that showed several results on *during a day*. In my medical practice, I often come across something like *Nausea **during a day** of long journey is expressed by the patient*

Comment: I guess when during has the meaning of [OALD's #1](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/during):"all through a period of time", during can license a/an, but in this case, it would mean 'a whole day', wouldn't it?

Comment: If your "already defined" conjecture was true, couldn't I reverse the sentence? ***He works at day and sleeps during the night***. But that's not how I'd say it; instead, I'd say: *He works during the day and sleeps at night.* I think Nico's "depends on the preposition" idea seems more on the right track.