# “I love nature there” VS “I love the nature there”

Tags: word-usage, definite-article, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Let’s say I asked someone where he/she is from and I like (the) nature (the natural environment) in that city he/she is from, can I say these sentences interchangeably:

- **Oh nice! I like nature there.**
- **Oh nice! I like the nature there.**

From what I see from my Google searches, **“the nature there”** is probably more common since we are talking about a specific part of nature, but I think the one without the article also sounds okay (It actually sounds better to my ears. I think I am more used to the usage of “nature” without the article) What do you think? I guess the sentences have slightly different senses but they can probably be used interchangeably.

Comment: This is just about definite article vs zero article and has been asked here countless times. Does this answer your question? [What makes the need of a definite article?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/what-makes-the-need-of-a-definite-article)

Comment: It actually doesn’t because there can be idiomatic differences depending on the word. My question is specifically about nature.

Comment: Speaking personally, I think "nature" refers to all plants and wildlife and landscapes in the world, rather than referring to a particular clump of trees. So saying "I like the nature there" or "I like nature there" both sound a bit odd. "I like the wildlife there" or "I like the plants there" or even "I like to enjoy nature there" or "...spend time in nature there" sound more natural. I'm not sure if dictionaries exactly agree with me on this, though.

Comment: @StuartF “natural scenery or countryside” is among the definitions here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nature

Comment: I agree with Stuart. The fact that 'natural scenery' is among the definitions doesn't mean it's idiomatic to speak of 'the nature there'.

Comment: @KateBunting Perhaps it is more American? I am way more used to American English and it doesn’t grate on me.

Comment: @FireandIce So what research have you done into 'nature' with zero article?

Comment: @StuartF -  I have seen German speakers write 'in the nature' when we would say e.g. 'in the open air', or 'in the countryside'.

Comment: My father, given to sarcasm, used to call the husband of my mother's best friend, 'Nature Boy'. I was told never to mention this to either of the couple or their son, my friend. I never did.

Comment: I don’t understand why my question would get negative votes though. I think that is a normal question any nonnative English speaker could ask.

Answer (score 1):

"I like the nature there" is correct and has the intended meaning of liking the natural beauty of that place.

"I like nature there" is odd because without specifying *which* nature, it sounds like your opinion about *nature in general* changes depending on where you are. So when you're there, you like nature, but when you're at home you don't like nature. Normally people's opinions don't change based on their location.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence simply states that the speaker likes whatever nature is present at the location.

The second states exactly the same thing, but depending on the context can imply that the speaker is not so happy with other elements of the location.

e.g.

*"I find the people noisy, but I like the nature there."*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I know what sort of English you speak? Two British users seem to not agree with you.

Comment: I speak English English. I don't think those people disagree. They are focusing more on the use of the word 'nature', than the presence of the definite article.

Comment: So your answer shows me that you don’t  agree with them in terms of the use of it.